# how to connect/run sequelize commands on the server?

Tags: node.js, heroku

set up - node js app with seqeulize. locally I run the sequelize db:migrate command. I am planning to deploy the app to heroku. once deployed, how can i run the same commands? is there a CLI ? can I login into to the mysql instance on heroku to run such commands? can this up as a part of the deployment/build process, the code is in github?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`heroku-postbuild` script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process) in your `package.json` to tell Heroku to run a command during deployment:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "sequelize db:migrate",
```